# Doubly Linked List Node Insertion in the end

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function for adding at the end for doubly linklist. I can't pinpoint out why it does not print out anything.

There was no error coming out when I build the program.

I am making sure 
1. new node check if the head has any value first

2. created following pointer that is previous current
3. I connected previous node to new node and new node point to previous node while new node point out to nullptr as next.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class list;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    friend class list;
};


class list {//double list 
    node* head;
    node* tail;
public:
    list(){ head = nullptr; tail = nullptr; head->next = tail; tail->prev = head;}
    node* pushback(int newdata) {
        node* curr = new node;
        curr->data = newdata;
        curr->next = nullptr;
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = curr;
            return head;
        }
        node*precurr = head;
        while (precurr->next != nullptr){
            precurr = precurr->next;
        }
        precurr->next = curr;
        curr->prev = precurr;
        return head;
    }
    void print() {
        while (head->next != nullptr) {
            cout << head->data << " " << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    list test;

    test.pushback(1);
    test.pushback(2);
    test.pushback(3);
    test.pushback(4);
    test.pushback(5);
    test.pushback(6);

    test.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `list` constructor has UB. You are setting `head` to `nullptr`, and then immediately using `head->next`.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a segmentation fault (which would be a more concerning symptom than not printing the contents of your list). When I fix the segmentation fault (UB), the code works. It's not great since it ignores `tail`, but it does print out the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a lot of things correctly, but you are confused on your constructor and on your use of the `->prev` and `tail` pointers.

You immediate issue with your constructor, as identified in the comments, is you set `head` and `tail` to `nullptr` and then  immediately derefernce both `head` and `tail` attempting to make `head` and `tail` self-referencing (which is only needed in a *circular linked-list*).

```
list(){ head = nullptr; tail = nullptr; head->next = tail; tail->prev = head;}
```

With `head` and `tail` to set to `nullptr`, you don't have a pointer to a valid `node` than can be dereferenced. Your attempt to set `head->next = tail; tail->prev = head;` fails immediately resulting in a SegFault.

For purposes on a normal *non-circular* list, you simply omit setting `head->next` and `tail->prev` in your constructor, e.g.

```
    list() { head = nullptr; tail = nullptr; }
```

If you want to make your list a circular list, then you will make `head` and `tail` self-referencing in:

```
    node *pushback (int newdata) {
        ...
        if (head == nullptr)     /* for circular-list 1st node initialization */
            head = tail = head->prev = head->next = tail->prev = tail->next = curr;
```

(**note:** a `tail` pointer is optional with a *circular* list as `head->prev` always points to the last node in the list)

Since your question pertains to a *double-linked-list* and not a *circular* list, you simply need to set both `head` and `tail` equal to the new node `curr` for the addition of the 1st node, e.g.

```
    node *pushback (int newdata) {
        node *curr = new node;
        curr->data = newdata;
        curr->next = curr->prev = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)
            head = tail = curr;
```

For all other nodes, there is NO iteration required (that's what a `tail` pointer is for), you simply set `curr->prev` to `tail`, `tail->next` to `curr` and then update the `tail` pointer to the new end node by setting `tail = curr;`, e.g.

```
        else {
            curr->prev = tail;
            tail->next = curr;
            tail = curr;
        }

        return head;
    }
```

The purpose of a *double-linked-list* is to allow you to iterate in both the forward and reverse direction over your nodes. For example:

```
    void printfwd() {
        node *iter = head;
        while (iter != nullptr) {
            std::cout << ' ' << iter->data;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    void printrev() {
        node *iter = tail;
        while (iter != nullptr) {
            std::cout << ' ' << iter->data;
            iter = iter->prev;
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
```

(the iteration scheme is slightly different for a circular list since you can iterate from any node in both forward and reverse direction without needed to start from `head` or `tail`. To insert in order for a circular list, you simply insert a new `tail` node).

Don't develop bad habits. [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696) Currently all you have to deal with is `cout` and `endl`, go ahead and remove `using namespace std;` and simply prefix `cout` and `endl` with `std::`.

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>

class list;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    friend class list;
};

class list {//double list 
    node *head;
    node *tail;
public:
    list() { head = nullptr; tail = nullptr; }
    node *pushback (int newdata) {
        node *curr = new node;
        curr->data = newdata;
        curr->next = curr->prev = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)
            head = tail = curr;
        else {
            curr->prev = tail;
            tail->next = curr;
            tail = curr;
        }

        return head;
    }
    void printfwd() {
        node *iter = head;
        while (iter != nullptr) {
            std::cout << ' ' << iter->data;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    void printrev() {
        node *iter = tail;
        while (iter != nullptr) {
            std::cout << ' ' << iter->data;
            iter = iter->prev;
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
};

int main() {

    list test;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        test.pushback(i);

    std::cout << "\nforward:\n";
    test.printfwd();
    std::cout << "\nreverse:\n";
    test.printrev();
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_double_int

forward:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

reverse:
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.